# Image Moving Outside Div

Tags: html, css, image

I am creating a website where a black div is in the center and an image in the center rotates when I hover over it. The problem is that though I placed the image in the div, it comes out of the div. How to fix it? This is my HTML code:

```js
const image = document.getElementById("pic");
image.classList.add("rotate");
const clone = image.cloneNode(true);
clone.classList.add("rotate-negative");
clone.classList.add("top-image");
clone.classList.add("shadow-lg");
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(clone);
```

```css
img {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.rotate{
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rotate-negative{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.top-image:hover{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
    max-height: 620px;
}
#container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToJI-yx2dCcsVf3fYDDRF908iRO_dlTsL9H32iWWIkT_1dYuimsdBUZKTIZgYC61z6Vik&usqp=CAU" id="pic">
</div>
```

I want the images to be placed inside the div. Though, I don't want to remove the "position" property from the CSS because it will ruin the design of the images in the center. Without removing the 'position' property, what can I do to force the images to remain inside the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding `position: relative` to your `#container` selector will do it. That keeps the positioning of the child elements relative to this element

If needed you could also add `overflow:hidden` to cut off anything that "overflows" outside of this element. I'm not sure if you want/need the second one though, so remove that if you don't need it.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("pic");
image.classList.add("rotate");
const clone = image.cloneNode(true);
clone.classList.add("rotate-negative");
clone.classList.add("top-image");
clone.classList.add("shadow-lg");
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(clone);
```

```css
img {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.rotate{
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rotate-negative{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.top-image:hover{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
    max-height: 620px;
}
#container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: black;
    
    /*added*/
    position: relative;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToJI-yx2dCcsVf3fYDDRF908iRO_dlTsL9H32iWWIkT_1dYuimsdBUZKTIZgYC61z6Vik&usqp=CAU" id="pic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
const image = document.getElementById("pic");
   image.classList.add("rotate");
   const clone = image.cloneNode(true);
   clone.classList.add("rotate-negative");
   clone.classList.add("top-image");
   clone.classList.add("shadow-lg");
   document.querySelector(".temp").appendChild(clone);
```

```css
body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        transform: translate(0%, 25%);
      }

      img {
        transition: 0.5s;
        max-height: 600px;
      }

      .rotate {
        transform: rotate(15deg);
      }

      .rotate-negative {
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
      }

      .top-image:hover {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        transition: 0.5s;
        max-height: 620px;
      }
      #container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 500px;
        width: 30%;
        min-width: 400px;
        background-color: black;
      }

      .temp {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .temp img {
        position: absolute;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image Rotation</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="temp">
        <img
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToJI-yx2dCcsVf3fYDDRF908iRO_dlTsL9H32iWWIkT_1dYuimsdBUZKTIZgYC61z6Vik&usqp=CAU"
          id="pic"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some minor changes on your CSS. This should work just fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Rotation</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    img {
      transition: 0.5s;
      max-height: 600px;
    }

    .rotate{
      transform: rotate(15deg);
      position: absolute;
      top: auto;
      left: auto;
    }

    .rotate-negative{
      transform: rotate(-5deg);
      position: absolute;
      top: auto;
      left: auto;
    }

    .top-image:hover{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        transition: 0.5s;
        max-height: 620px;
    }
    #container{
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 500px;
        width: 30%;
        background-color: black;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcToJI-yx2dCcsVf3fYDDRF908iRO_dlTsL9H32iWWIkT_1dYuimsdBUZKTIZgYC61z6Vik&usqp=CAU" id="pic">
  </div>

  <script>
    const image = document.getElementById("pic");
    image.classList.add("rotate");
    const clone = image.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.add("rotate-negative");
    clone.classList.add("top-image");
    clone.classList.add("shadow-lg");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(clone);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```